# How to delete a boot partition from MacOS Catalina

Tags: macos, partition, catalina, diskutil

A few years ago I created a second boot partition on a MacBook, called "BootOS". I would like to delete this partition and merge the space back into the remaining partition.

I have found a question/answer that describes [how to do this on El Capitan](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/239122/merge-partitions-with-disk-utility-in-el-capitan-gives-operation-failed-error), but the output from `diskutils list` on Catalina looks sufficiently different for me to ask again.

Can anyone suggest suggest how I should go about this?

diskutil list :

```
/dev/disk0 (internal, physical):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        *1.0 TB     disk0
   1:                        EFI EFI                     209.7 MB   disk0s1
   2:                 Apple_APFS Container disk2         937.0 GB   disk0s2
   3:          Apple_CoreStorage BootOS                  62.7 GB    disk0s3
   4:                 Apple_Boot Recovery HD             650.0 MB   disk0s4

/dev/disk1 (internal, virtual):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:                  Apple_HFS BootOS                 +62.3 GB    disk1
                                 Logical Volume on disk0s3
                                 98445A01-48FA-4E17-8CDE-61C46B885B90
                                 Unencrypted

/dev/disk2 (synthesized):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      APFS Container Scheme -                      +937.0 GB   disk2
                                 Physical Store disk0s2
   1:                APFS Volume Macintosh HD - Data     850.8 GB   disk2s1
   2:                APFS Volume Preboot                 85.1 MB    disk2s2
   3:                APFS Volume Recovery                526.6 MB   disk2s3
   4:                APFS Volume VM                      1.1 GB     disk2s4
   5:                APFS Volume Macintosh HD            11.0 GB    disk2s5
```

diskutil cs list :

```
CoreStorage logical volume groups (1 found)
|
+-- Logical Volume Group 1C402269-ED55-46B6-B2B3-2C83C455625C
    =========================================================
    Name:         BootOS
    Status:       Online
    Size:         62708625408 B (62.7 GB)
    Free Space:   18984960 B (19.0 MB)
    |
    +-< Physical Volume 8A71BD1E-3901-4573-8ABA-B635F6957E9B
    |   ----------------------------------------------------
    |   Index:    0
    |   Disk:     disk0s3
    |   Status:   Online
    |   Size:     62708625408 B (62.7 GB)
    |
    +-> Logical Volume Family CD18710F-BC90-4354-843B-C8B35B34274A
        ----------------------------------------------------------
        Encryption Type:         None
        |
        +-> Logical Volume 98445A01-48FA-4E17-8CDE-61C46B885B90
            ---------------------------------------------------
            Disk:                  disk1
            Status:                Online
            Size (Total):          62337318912 B (62.3 GB)
            Revertible:            Yes (no decryption required)
            LV Name:               BootOS
            Volume Name:           BootOS
            Content Hint:          Apple_HFS
```

Comment: I'll take a stab at an answer - I don't have a test system to run thought - you might not need the cs delete once you've ejected disk1 - but the rest are pretty straightforward

Answer (score 1):

Disk Utility.app in the /Applications/Utilities/ folder would be my recommendation. That's generally the easiest/safest way to make changes to partitions.

Comment: I tried diskutil first, but the BootOS volume doesn’t seem to be removable. Perhaps I should erase it first.

Answer (score 0):

what about:

```
diskutil ejectDisk disk1
diskutil cs delete disk0s3
```

That cleans the space that was reserved and the next says grow to fit (since it doesn't make sense to size an exiting container to 0 - that is a shortcut to grow as far as it can)

```
diskutil apfs resizeContainer disk0s2 0
```

Of course if you or I am wrong, you need a backup of everything so I hope you have that before starting.

Comment: I do have a backup. I’d prefer not to have to use it ;)

Comment: I think you’ll be fine if you copy and paste the disk0s2 from your listing and double check you didn’t miss a column / row